# How to create stacked histogram using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am very new to Python and start to learn matplotlib recently. I have a dataset which have one 5 independent variables and 1 dependent variable. I want to create a stacked histogram which can show the variable distribution within independent variable.

Here is my raw data-
Country, age, new_use, source and total_pages_visited are independent variables. Converted is dependent variable. I want to create separate stacked histogram for each independent variables. And in each histogram, it shows the distribution of variable and mark the different category of 'converted' in different color.

Comment: Welcome to SO, zywwill11. Could you please tell us what you have tried so far?

Comment: The notions of independent and dependent variable are confusing for a histogram, because a histogram shows the distribution (usually shown on the y axis) along a single dimension (usually shown on the xaxis). Maybe you are looking for a bar plot instead?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest  Thanks! You are right, I need the bar plot instead. Here is the expected chart- take 'Country' for example, the plot can show the frequency of each country in three bar (there are 3 different countries). And in each bar, it shows the distribution of "Converted-Yes' and "Converted-No'. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is **stacked bar plot** and you can use `pandas` to achieve it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.asarray([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]),index=['A','B','C'], columns=['Converted-Yes', 'Converted-No'])

df.plot.bar(stacked=True)
plt.show()
```

The above code generates the plot:

[image: plot]